# Schengen visa fingers prints

Tags: visa, schengen

After how long will my Schengen visa finger prints will be destroyed from the Schengen system?

Comment: Schengen visas, specifically type A airport transit visas and type C uniform short stay visas, are generally off topic here. Instead, you should ask at [Travel.SE]. If your visa is a national (type D visa), the rules regarding retention of your fingerprints may vary from country to country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [http://ec.europa.eu](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en)

> **How is my data in VIS protected?**
>
> Access to VIS data is limited to authorised staff in the performance
>   of their tasks. They must ensure that the use of VIS data is limited
>   to that which is necessary, appropriate and proportionate for carrying
>   out their tasks.
>
> Data is kept in the VIS for **five years**. This retention period starts
>   from the expiry date of the issued visa, the date a negative decision
>   is taken or the date a decision to modify an issued visa is taken. Any
>   person has the right to be informed about his/her data in the VIS. Any
>   person may request that inaccurate data about him/her is corrected and
>   unlawfully recorded data is deleted.